# NSData is not a subtype of NSData?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am geting the error:

NSData is not a subtype of NSData from my code below, what am I doing wrong?

```
let urlPath = "myurl"
var url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    if error {
        println(error)
    } else {
        println(data)
    }
})

task.resume()
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: The error is on the line with the let task = session.dataTAskWithRequest... I am using the latest xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error message is `'NSData!' is not a subtype of 'NSData'` (notice the ! after `NSData`)

`NSURL(string:)` is a [failable initializer](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=17), which is new in Swift 1.1 (Xcode 6.1).  Failable initializers return an optional that will be `nil` upon failure.

You must check for failure before you can use the url:

```
let urlPath = "myurl"
if let url = NSURL(string: urlPath) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            println(data)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is very misleading. The real issue is that `NSURL(string:)` is a failable initializer, so it returns an optional. But `dataTaskWithRequest` doesn't take an `NSURL?` it takes an `NSURL`

Theres another error in your code, error isn't a boolean so you need to compare it to nil. Here's the code that compiles:

```
let urlPath = "myurl"
if let url = NSURL(string: urlPath) {
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        } else {
            println(data)
        }
    })
}
```